# Are closed subsets of a locally compact space, locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

I know that there are open subsets of locally compact topological spaces that are not locally compact ($\mathbb{Q}$ in the Alexandroff's compactification).

*I wonder if any closed subset of a locally compact space is always locally compact.*

**Definition**. $(X,\tau)$ is locally compact if for each $x\in X$, there is a neighborhood of  $x, A_x\in \tau:closure(A_x)$ is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Credit to my prof, not myself) Let $Y$ closed subspace of locally compact space $X$, and let $y\in Y$.  Since $X$ is locally compact, there exists compact subset $K \subseteq X$ and open $U\subseteq X$ such that $y \in U \subseteq K$.  Now let
$$ V= Y \cap U \subseteq Y $$
$$ and $$
$$ K_0 = Y \cap K \subseteq Y$$
so that $y \in V \subseteq K_0$.  Notice $V$ is open by definition of the subspace topology, so we are left to show $K_0$ is compact.

Note that since $Y$ is closed in $X$, $K_0$ is a closed subset of $K$ when equipped with the subspace topology.  Hence $K_0$ is compact, as a closed subset of the compact space $K$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, $Y$ is locally compact

Comment: You showed that $K_0$ is compact, as a closed subset of the compact space $K$. This implies that $K_0$ is compact in the subspace $Y$? It seems right, but there are too many subspaces there, and then I got a little confused how to do the connections.

Answer (score 1):

Take $F $ to be a closed subset of a locally compact space $X $. Then, for every $U $, open subset of $F$, there exists $V $, open subset of $X $ such that $U $ is the intersection of $V $ and $F $ by definition of the induced topology.
Let $x \in F $ and $V $ be a compact neighborhood of $x $ in $X $. $V \cap F $ is compact and is a neighborhood of $x $ in $F $ because $V$ contains an open subset of $X $ $U $ containing $x $, so $U \cap F $ is open in $F$. Thus $V \cap F $ fits. So it is true.